# If most satellites in orbit were destroyed from debris, would we ever be able to recover?

Tags: satellites

Suppose enough satellites were destroyed in orbit to cause so much debris from the explosions that a [chain reaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kessler_syndrome) destroying other satellites took over to generating more and more debris (even destroying the ISS).

If this were to occur, would we be able to recover? Would our geostationary orbit be rendered useless? Would the debris eventually fall back into atmosphere and burn? If so, how long would that take? Is that too much time for mankind to live without its telecommunications?

Comment: I don't think satellites or debris can be in the same orbit at different _speeds_.

Comment: There are over [1000](http://www.universetoday.com/42198/how-many-satellites-in-space/) operational satellites up in space (plus a few hundred-to-thousand that are not operational). If someone blew up a few of them, I believe that we'd be fine.

Comment: China destroyed a satellite in orbit blasting tons of debris into space.  The Gravity premise is highly exaggerated.  Google "China Orbital Debris" for more information.  There are just to many aspects of the story to find a good single article to link to.

Comment: It is called the Kessler effect/syndrome. Google that and you will get much better information than here.